# PHP Regex on CD Tracklists

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm using `preg_match` to format tracklists so the track number, title and duration are separated into their own cells in a table:

```
<td>01</td><td>Track Title</td><td>01:23</td>
```

The problem is that the tracks themselves can take any of the following forms (the leading zeros on the track numbers and durations are not always present):

```
01. Track Title (01:23)
01. Track Title 01:23
01. Track Title
1 Track Title (01:23)
1 Track Title 01:23
1 Track Title
```

The following only works on tracks with a timestamp:

```
/([0-9]+)\.?[\s+](.*)[\s+](\?[0-5]?[0-9]:[0-5][0-9]\)?)/
```

So I added `?` to the timestamp:

```
/([0-9]+)\.?[\s+](.*)[\s+]((\?[0-5]?[0-9]:[0-5][0-9]\)?)?/
```

This then works for tracks without a timestamp, but tracks with a timestamp end up with the timestamp stuck with the title, like so:

```
<td>01</td><td>Track Title 01:23</td><td></td>
```

EDIT: The tracklists are plaintext and are being pulled from an SQL table before parsing.

Comment: +1 for your attempts. Wouldn't using an html parser be easier ? Think about [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/).

Comment: You could always do a bit of logic and use multiple regex - e.g. check for a ':' near the end of the string if it's there then use one regex to grab the timestamp in any format.  The advantage of this approach is that when you find another corner case (like a song named 0:00 or something) it's easier to fix than trying to fix your one huge regex.

Comment: @Karl with your last edit, do you mean there are no `<td>` tags ?

Comment: @HamZa Sorry, I forgot to add that the tracklists are plain text. So yeah, there are no html tags.

Comment: @Karl lolwut, then why did you add it. I came to this [`(\d+)\.?\s*(.*?)\s*(\(\d+:\d+\)|\d+:\d+|$)`](http://regex101.com/r/mA9hE1) solution. You'll need to loop through group 3 and trim `()` if that's needed ...

Comment: Because I'm parsing the plaintext into an HTML table using preg_match. Thanks, that one worked perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/^([0-9]+)\.?[\s]+(.*)([\s]+(\(?[0-5]?[0-9]:[0-5][0-9]\)?))?$/U
```

Note I am used ungreedy pattern modifier `U` to try to match smallest matching string and I have anchored the beginning and end of the string.

Comment: Same results, my friend :(

Comment: @Karl [Regexoverflow](http://regex101.com/r/rB4yH3) : `(?m)^([0-9]+)\.?\s+(.*?)\s*\(?([0-5]?[0-9]:[0-5][0-9])?\)?$`

Answer (score 0):

By default regular expressions are greedy so the part for matching title `.*`  eats the rest of the string because last part with duration is optional.

Use `/U` modifier to turn on ungreedy behavior - look for `PCRE_UNGREEDY` on
https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
^([0-9]+)\.?\s+(.*?)(?:\(?([0-5]?[0-9]:[0-5][0-9])\)?)?$
```

**explanation:**

The regular expression:

```
(?-imsx:^([0-9]+)\.?\s+(.*?)(?:\(?([0-5]?[0-9]:[0-5][0-9])\)?)?$)

matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?-imsx:                 group, but do not capture (case-sensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]+                   any character of: '0' to '9' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \.?                      '.' (optional (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the least amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \(?                      '(' (optional (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \3:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [0-5]?                   any character of: '0' to '5' (optional
                               (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [0-9]                    any character of: '0' to '9'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      :                        ':'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [0-5]                    any character of: '0' to '5'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [0-9]                    any character of: '0' to '9'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \3
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \)?                      ')' (optional (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```